# How can i only check one model with ModelState.IsValid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, modelstate, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm trying to only check one model with `ModelState.IsValid` once, after that I want to check another model with `ModelState.IsValid` and I want to do it all in one action.
Let me show to you what I really want to do below:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
 public async Task<IActionResult> FillingInformation(Company company, Agency agency, List<IFormFile> files, Address address)
 {
   if (ModelState.IsValid("Company"))//if its possible
    {
        //.....
    }
    else if (ModelState.IsValid("Agency"))//if its possible
    {
        //.....
    }
    else if (ModelState.IsValid("Address"))//if its possible
    {
        //.....
    }
    else
    {
        //.....
    }
 }
```

I already searched and tried to apply it to my code such as things like: `GetFieldValidationState` , `ValidationState` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelValidationState` but I just could not apply them well.

I tried to write an extension method which checks `ModelState.IsValid` but it still checking both models not one.

Comment: Please limit your tags to the actual framework and version that you are using. For instance, you cannot be simultaneously be using ASP.NET MVC 3 and ASP.NET MVC 4 and ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am using something like this.

```
try {
    var context = new ValidationContext(Company, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
    var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
    if (!Validator.TryValidateObject(Company, context, results, true))
        throw new Exception("Check Company info...");

    //validate all models
}
catch (Exception e) {
    ModelState.AddModelError("", e.Message);
    return View("your_view");
}
```